# reactJS изучение

Tags: javascript, reactjs

я начинающий программист я изучаю языки дома, самостоятельно, знаю html/css JS, хочу изучить reactJS,смотрел видеоролики learnJS которые бесплатные, и не очень все понял, можете посоветовать бесплатные книги или видеоролики или сайты где объясняют максимально детально и понятно.....буду блогадарень.

Comment: https://youtu.be/gb7gMluAeao

Answer (score -1):

Посмотри обучающие видео:

[Основы ES6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4YfsAz-sNAo&list=PLqHlAwsJRxAOpWPtj2T6HhSzX-lKmKV2q)

[React уроки](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORHEXyN-ktE&list=PLIcAMDxr6tpoShAiU0Nh_nBtg19XWbCql)